# Как правильно подключить SQL Server к Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Я только только начал изучать C# с ASP.net фреймворк. Я новичок.  Мне необходимо подключить базу на Visual Studio. Я установил себе 1) Visual Studio 2017, 2) SQL Server 2017, 3) SQL Server management studio 17. 
Но при подключения через верхнего вкладочек  ***Средства/Подключиться*** потом в открывшемся окне выбираю ***Microsoft SQL Server*** а имя сервера: ***ACER_NOTEBOOK***. ВЫВОДИТ СЛЕД. ОШИБКУ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вообще можно ли установить SQL Server и SQL Server management studio на диск D, при этом Visual Studio установив на диск C, подключиться вообще..?

БУДУ ОЧЕНЬ БЛАГОДАРЕН..

Comment: не важно в какие папки вы ставите этот софт, главное, что на один комп. При локальном подключении можете сервер указать как точку `.`

Comment: А `SQL Server management studio 17` успешно подключилась? Если да, то возьмите строку подключения оттуда.

Comment: Да, SQL Server management studio и SQL Server подключил.. 
щась попробую...